# Validate WYSIWYG editor textarea

Tags: php

I am using WYSIWYG editor box as textarea  in a form in my website. I want to validate the textarea (From WYSIWYG) . Can you say any suggestion to validate this textarea (Not normal textarea added from WYSIWYG  editor) in javascript?

Comment: Didn't got your question

Comment: erm, if I understood correctly, you need w3c validator?

Comment: or you want to check it as required field i.e. whether it is empty or not?

Comment: If user not entered any text in the editor box, the form should not be submitted. I need to validate from javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, hope it will help

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#formId").submit(function(){
        var textArea = $('#textArea').val();

        if (textArea == "") {
              textArea.show();
              textArea.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            return true; 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: But, this is for normal textarea validation. I need editor validation. Thanks

Comment: This is the coding part I am using for editor.<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="components/com_camassistant/assets/wysiwyg.js"></script>
<textarea id="textarea2" name="SNOTES" class="textarea" style=" width:656px; height:130px;" ><?PHP echo $SPL_REQ_TABS[6]->Notes; ?></textarea>
<script language="javascript1.2">
generate_wysiwyg('textarea2');
</script>

Comment: This is my form link. I need validation for Comment area.             http://camassistant.com/dev/editor.php

Comment: I think you can validate the normal textarea, so textarea2 because the editor should put the data in there while you edit.